# How to sort a multidimensional array in a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, arraylist, multidimensional-array, array-multisort

I'm not able to solve this problem. I tried mostly everything.

I'm doing a home project with a database of song artists and their songs but i stumbled over a big problem which i cannot solve. I read most stackoverflow posts but none helped. I bombarded google with questions about php sorting methods and tried them but without success.

I would really appreciate help. I'm stuck on this for 3 days now...

Here is my problem:

I have my array with my artists ($arr) now how can i sort every **song** array of each **artist** by **year**? The data comes from an **.json file**.

```
$arr = array(
    "artists" => array(
        "1" => array(
            "id" => "1",
            "firstname" => "John",
            "lastname" => "Doe",
            "songs" => array(
                array("name" => "song_1", "year" => "1999"),
                array("name" => "song_2", "year" => "1987")
            ),
        ),
        "2" => array(
            "id" => "2",
            "firstname" => "Jane",
            "lastname" => "Doe",
            "songs" => array(
                array("name" => "song_1", "year" => "2000"),
                array("name" => "song_2", "year" => "1999")
            )
        ),
        "3" => array(
            "id" => "3",
            "firstname" => "Mark",
            "lastname" => "Doe",
            "songs" => array(
                array("name" => "song_1", "year" => "1984"),
                array("name" => "song_2", "year" => "1983")
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I hope, my problem is clear enough. I'm new here and i'm not really friends yet with all the buttons. I just can't wait, to hopefully solve this...

Comment: What did you try so far? Even if it didn't work, show what you tried so far.

Comment: if it comes from database then you can do `order by year ASC` (while fetching songs array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_walk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). `array_walk()` is to make an iteration over the array and `usort()` is to sorting the songs by `ASC` or `DESC` order.

```
array_walk($arr['artists'], function (&$song) {
    usort($song['songs'], function ($a, $b) { return $a['year'] > $b['year'] ? 1 : -1; }); // Ascending order
    //usort($song['songs'], function ($a, $b) { return $a['year'] < $b['year'] ? 1 : -1; }); // Descending order
});
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/M8Vs8)

Comment: Your code was very helpful to find a solution but i don't really understand what you actually did... It would really help me for my future programming, if you could describe your code in a very short version. For example: what does the &-sing mean on the first line   ```array_walk($arr['artists'], function (&$song) {...```

Comment: It is call by reference. For details: https://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php